# PayPal JS SDK buttons: enable only when a user county is selected

Tags: paypal

I want to enable and disable the PayPal button(s) depending on certain user inputs in an input form. Below is part script where the button should only be active when the user has selected a country. I am using a variable to change to 1 when a country is selected, but the action enable is not working.

```
let payPalBtn_status = 0; // variable set paypal status

$(document).ready(function () {
    initPayPalButton(); //iniate button place on DOM
    $('#country_shipping').on('change', function(e){
        var country = $('#country_shipping :selected').val();
        if (country != 'none'){
            payPalBtn_status = 1;  // if country select has been selected status = 1
        }
    });
})



function initPayPalButton() {
    paypal.Buttons({
        onInit: function(data, actions){
            actions.disable();
            if (payPalBtn_status == 1){
                actions.enable(); // if paypal status variable is equal to 1 button to be enabled
            }
        },
        style: {
            shape: 'rect',
            color: 'gold',
            layout: 'vertical',
            label: 'paypal',
        },

  createOrder: function(data, actions) {
    return actions.order.create({
      purchase_units: [{
          "reference_id":"123456789",
          "description":"Sticker, ref_id: 1234567",
          "amount":{
              "currency_code":"GBP",
              "value":4,
                    }}]
    });
  },
  onApprove: function(data, actions) {
    return actions.order.capture().then(function(orderData) {
    });
  },

  onError: function(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}).render('#paypal-button-container');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the synchronous event listener to inside onInit. There is an example [in the documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/customize/validate-user-input/#link-synchronousvalidation).

Adapting it from a checkbox to a "#country_shipping" element that has a value...

```
  paypal.Buttons({

    // onInit is called when the button first renders
    onInit: function(data, actions) {

      // Disable the buttons
      actions.disable();

      // Listen for changes...
      document.querySelector('#country_shipping')
        .addEventListener('change', function(event) {

          // Enable or disable the button when it has a value
          if (event.target.value) {
            actions.enable();
          } else {
            actions.disable();
          }
        });
    },
```

Comment: great thanks I though I could do this outside the onInit but this works ok I can so a onclick for the cart div and see if my status variable has changed. This was i van have more checks with one variable status

Comment: A usual pattern is to declare a validation function in onInit that checks everything and calls actions disable/enable, and add this function as an on change listener to everything